# Database Couldn't Be Found In Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access

I've been creating an application using Visual Studio 2010 C# and Microsoft Access 2007. I am new to this and I am experiencing some errors. I've tried using MySQL as a database before but when I changed it to MS Access 2007, there are errors occured stating that the database format is not recognized.

Here's the print screen:
[image]

The file type of the database I created is **.accdb**. 
Please help. Thanks

Comment: Why are you only pretty sure the file exists? I'd suggest using Windows Explorer to ensure it exists.

Comment: Sorry to point to the obvious, but does C:\gxi.accdb exist in Windows Explorer?

Comment: @NathanialWoolls: Thanks for the help. Got new errors though. I just edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver you are using to connect accdb database is outdated, install [Access 2010 Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255) and then change your connection string in this way :

```
string MyConString = Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\pathofyourDatabase.accdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the database is encrypted or you don't have the proper Access engine for the architecture (x86/x64). Visual Studio is also 32-bit and probably can't connect to x64 database. See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/accessdev/thread/2fdd547a-aeb9-48f8-9242-9159eb1d33bb).